# do I no longer have to explicitly include signer and system program accounts in my transaction (anchor)?

Tags: anchor, signer, systemprogram

this is the context in my smart contract:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Send<'info>  {
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"pda"], bump = pda.bump)] 
    pub pda: Account<'info, MyData>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

I found that I only needed to explicitly pass in "pda", and not "user" or "system program". Has that always been the case?

```
    await program.methods.send(new anchor.BN(3)) //10000000 is 0.01 SOL
    .accounts({
      pda: PDA,
      //user: anchor.AnchorProvider.env().wallet.publicKey, <= I swear this used to be necessary?!
      //systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId
    }).rpc().then(() => print_lamports(PDA));
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a new feature of the anchor client, it was introduced a few versions ago. You can check the [changelog](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0210---2022-02-07), it was in v21 I think